# Is there a way to customize the authentication mechanism on an Android Device?

Tags: passwords, password-management, android, password-cracking, password-policy

Android comes with authentication mechanisms like the lockscreen pattern. Is there a way to customize those patterns (e.g. adding nodes, changing colors, modifying the ruleset)? Or can I even implement a whole new authentication type (e.g. using emojis instead of numbers).

The Android version is not important (so is the way to implement my needs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build your custom version of Android (so called `mod`), the answer is yes. AOSP includes all the code for lock screen, and you are free to replace it, or modify it as you like.